# Update github project that has had wrok done locally

Tags: git

Here's my current situation:

I downloaded Dolibar 16.0.3 from the releases page and unzipped it on my local machine.

Then I git inited my own repository and push everything to a selfhosted Bonobo remote as a branch called "clean" which is just that, Dolibarr 16.0.3 as it came from github.

Then I created a branch called "custom" where I worked on my own stuff.

Now I want to update to 16.0.5.

I tried:

- Copying the folder
- Renaming it to Dolibarr16.0.5
- Adding the github project as a fetch remote
- fetching all tags
- `git rebase --onto < commit for 16.0.5 > < commit for clean branch > custom`

Then I fixed conflicts and everything seemd to work fine but I don't know If I did the correct thing.

Surely copying and pasting the folder was not how I should do it because I assume the .git folder still points to the old Dolibarr16.0.3 remote

I also have 4 branches checkout to their own folders outside the main repo folder. (Righ now I just make changes in "custom" and rebase each branch to custom so they all have the changes, RR enabled to automate a bit of merging)

Should I just clone the project from github from scratch and move my custom branch over to it? How would the update process work, just rebase my custom branch to whatever tag I want?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to:

- clone the [`Dolibarr/dolibarr`](https://github.com/Dolibarr/dolibarr) directly
- create your own branch on top of the [16.03 tag](https://github.com/Dolibarr/dolibarr/releases/tag/16.0.3)
- add the self-hosted Bonobo remote to push any branch you want
- rebase your branch on top of the [16.05 tag](https://github.com/Dolibarr/dolibarr/releases/tag/16.0.5) when ready.

Plus, you can have separate folder per tag if you want, using the [`git worktree` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309).

Comment: If, after I add the bonobo remote, I set my newly created "custom" branch to track the remote "custom" branch with all the old commits should I just be able to do a `git pull` and get all my custom changes on the new repo that tracks both github and bonobo? And then I can just rebase every time I want to update the base e.g. to v17?

Comment: @Daviid Is the bonobo remote repository a clone of the original Dolibarr/dolibarr repository with all its history?

Comment: no, I created my bonobo repo from a zipped download of 16.0.3

Comment: @Daviid That is why my answer is about working from Dolibarr/dolibarr and pushing to your Bonobo remote only what you want. That way, you do have related histories instead of unrelated ones.